# Facebook IE9 Javascript error

Tags: javascript, facebook, internet-explorer-9

This morning our game is not working on my computer under IE9. The error I get is:

```
access denied on 

http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v1/yL/r/X3oFUDWWu05.js
```

When I load this URL in Chrome, FF, and IE 8,  everything works fine. But under IE9 I have the following error:

```
'window is undefined'
Error : 800A1391
Execution Error Microsoft JScript
```

This is a Facebook script that I have no control over.  I've cleared my cache but still get the error.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing. After this error there's several more JS errors all originating from the facebook like button iframe.

Comment: It looks like this is only happening when IE9 is in compatibility view/IE7 mode.